# What is a word that groups patent, trademark and copyrightable work?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a catch-all term. Do we say "intellectual property work" or
"intellectual property content" or something else?

For example,

> At the moment, the best solution is to file their work with intellectual property office in specific jurisdictions where the creators wish to protect their IPs.

Could I say "their work?"

Comment: Just *intellectual property*, I think. Can you add an example sentence with a fill-in-the-blank ____ where you want to use this word?

Comment: @TinfoilHat I just added one.

Comment: You can *register* your *intangibles* at the IP office. But IP is only a subset of intangible assets : corporate reputation is an intangible asset.

Comment: *Proprietary creations*?

Answer (score 2):

Protected works.
That's what  patents, trademarks and copyrights do.
They protect.

Comment: I think the question is actually asking what you call _the things_ that are protected (although it's not that clear).

Comment: They're protected by law. More so than other kinds of property.

Comment: This is an awkward fit in the OP's example sentence, as it would describe IP filing as a means of "protecting protected works", but the purpose of filing in the first place is that the work may not yet be protected. An invention that is not yet patented may not be "protected work".

Answer (score 0):

As Tinfoil Hat has already pointed out in a comment, the term *intellectual property* is itself perfectly adequate for the purpose. It works fine in the OP's sample sentence:

> ...where the creators wish to protect their intellectual property.